# Asp.net MVC routing parameters in different order

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a roting rule for

```
jobs/region-rome/type-wedding
maped to

public ActionResult Jobs(string region, string type)
```

and for

```
jobs/type-wedding/region-rome
mapped to

public ActionResult Jobs(string region, string type)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are `type` and `region` actually appearing in the URL or not? If they are, you can use route constraints like this: `new { region = @"^region-(\w)*$" }`. If they are not then it's almost impossible unless you have a predefined list of regions that can be used to limit the route matching

Comment: If `type-` and `region-` appear in the url, you could also define 2 routes like `"jobs/region-{region}/type-{type}"` and `"jobs/type-{type}/region-{region}"` without needing a constraint.

Comment: possible routes
  
jobs/type-wedding/region-rome,
jobs/type-wedding/,
jobs/region-rome/type-wedding,
jobs/region-rome/,  
jobs/region-moscow/type-wedding,    
jobs/region-moscow/,  
jobs/type-kids/region-rome,  
  
and so on

Comment: Then @DanielJ.G. is right, just define the routes as he says and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you

I define 2 routes

        [Route(@"jobs/{region:regex(^region-(\w)*$)?}/{type:regex(^type-(\w)*$)?}")]
        [Route(@"jobs/{type:regex(^type-(\w)*$)?}{region:regex(^region-(\w)*$)?}/")]

but what if we need more params region, type, contractor, event - 4 params for example - need manual parsing?

Comment: found appropriate solution http://yojimbo87.github.io/2012/07/05/parsing-url-path-action-object-parameter-asp-net-mvc.html